# Java Transport mail sender error

Tags: java, mailer, transport

I'm need to send an email after persist an object on my JAVA project, I'm using this code

```
   public static void sendMail(String protocol, String host, String port, final String userName, final String password, 
           String subject, byte[] content, String para, String cc, String co) {
       Properties props = getServerProperties(protocol, host, port);

       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
       });

       try {
             final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(para));
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(co));
             message.setSubject(subject);
             message.setText(content.toString());
             Transport.send(message);
       } catch (MessagingException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
    }

   private static Properties getServerProperties(String protocol, String host, String port) {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.host", protocol), host);
      properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.port", protocol), port);
      properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.class", protocol), "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
      properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.fallback", protocol), "false");
      properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.port", protocol), String.valueOf(port));
      return properties;
   }
```

but when I call **Transport.send(message);** returns me an error message

*Can't make API call mail.Send in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager*

What i'm doing wrong on mailer?

Comment: I believe nothing wrong with you mail sending code, there's something to happen before this method is invoked, are you creating any separate threads or submitting any runnables into executor?

Comment: the app have some execution routine in threads, but nothing related on persist or mailer method